# What constitute as prior art that an examiner or PTAB petitioner can use against an application?

Tags: prior-art

And more specifically, could something discussed here on stackoverflow be counted as published prior art?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely anything that is publicly disclosed before an application is filed is potentially prior art. Yes, something posted on Stack Exchange may be used as prior art.